# Android Application Connecting To Database

Tags: java, android, database

I want to create an android application that uses a shared database that can be updated.  I want my application to check the database on startup and then possibly store info locally.  I have a website, is there a way to create an online database and have it connect and read / modify?  I want to be able to add data whenever I want and for it to show in an installed public application.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase by Google](https://firebase.google.com/)

You can use firebase as per your desired need you can create a well managed database through firebase and also you can get Analysis report and Bug report and so on...